# Using 3 date fields over 2 tables in Power BI

Tags: date, charts, powerbi, relationship

I am new to Power BI and need to display a visual showing data requests, deadlines and returns. I have the idea of a line and clustered bar chart - the line to show the amount of notices given to a business from the date a data notice is given to the deadline date. The bars can then show the amount of data received.

 
I have two table in Power BI. `Notices` and `Historical Data`. 
`Notices` contains the fields - `Business Name`, `Amount of Notices`, `Request Date` and `Deadline`. 
`Historical Data` contains the fields - `Business Name`, `Amount Returned` and `Return Date`.  
I have the tables in a relationship using `Business Name` in a many-to-many join. I have tried several attempts to create charts however struggling with the fact there are 3 date fields.  I cannot get them to show in one chart together. I attempted to create a table with the appended date fields from each table and then create relationships between the new date table and the original tables however this cannot be done with the original tables having an active relationship as well. The visual also needs to be able to filter using slicers etc so all relationships need to be active.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Even another visual if recommended as I am new to Power BI.  It's worth noting I would like to create a Gantt chart but do not have the add-on. 
Thanks.
Additional info:
Tables are below.
The business name can appear many times in each table as the requests are annually and they will have several data return records for each notice request.
 
`Historical Data`
[image] 
`Notices`[image]

Comment: Can you add example of the tables,you might just need a calendar table to link things together

Comment: Hi Jon, I have added a couple of screenshots of the tables.  Any help would be great.  Anything else you need to know please ask.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi Jon, I took on your advice and included a calendar table and brought in the amounts for each date for the 3 date fields and created a relationship to each table.  The problem is the originally relationship between the tables has to be inactive.  Meaning that any visuals cannot be filtered, which is also needed.  Do you know a way to get around this.  Sorry to bombard you!  Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: @Burner, can you provide a visual mockup based on the data (along with an explanation and links to values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question I think the issue you have is that with the calendar table you can only have one active relationship on a table, so for example you should have something like this. (I have also added a Business Name table to remove cross filtering between the to tables).

I've used this example data:

[image]

And offset the deadline by 6 days

[image]

So by using the calendar table you can map to date the values for the 'Amount Returned' via the Return Data & 'Amount of Notices' by the Deadline date, but can't see values for the 'Request Date', and doesn't show them correctly.

[image]

So if 16th Jan is selected you'll get:

[image]

When it should just be a value of 15 for 'Total by Deadline'

What you have to do is create two measures one that uses the active and one that will use the inactive relationship via [USERELATIONSHIP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/userelationship-function-dax)
So for example:

```
    Total by Deadline = SUM(Notices[Amount of Notices])
    Total by Request = CALCULATE(SUM(Notices[Amount of Notices])
                      , USERELATIONSHIP('Calendar'[Date], Notices[Request Date]))
```

The USERELATIONSHIP forces the measure to use the inactive relationships, and should allow you to filter via selected dates correctly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Jon this is more help than I would have expected so I can't thank you enough.  I have just been putting this into place.  I actually had something quite similar as I stumbled upon the USERELATIONSHIP function.  My only remaining issue is, even with the Business Name table I am still struggling to filter my visuals, e.g to show by Business Name.  I've thought of adding a Business Name field to the calendar but the problem here is that the Calendar date field is one record per day, however I will have some instances where more than one Business name appears in a days count.  If that makes sense.

Comment: Add a separate table that combines the unique values of the business names, In power query, create query based on the two table that appends the business name table together and de-dups it. Like in my above diagram, that should allow filtering a bit easier. If you having issues with that bit raise another question.